# Do functors between equivalent categories necessarily form equivalent categories

Tags: category-theory, functors

Say, if $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}, G: \mathcal{C} \leftarrow \mathcal{D}$ give an equivalence of the categories $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$,F,G), could there also be $F',G'$, that don't give an equivalence of catgories?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking if every functor $\mathcal C \longrightarrow \mathcal D$ gives an equivalence of categories, once we know that $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are equivalent? This is definitely not true. (Not even true for equivalent sets, i.e. having a bijection.)

Comment: I have fixed the language of the question

Comment: For an obvious counter-example, take the following functor $F$ from the category of abelian group to itself : for any group $X$, put $F(X)=0$ (the trivial group) and for any morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, put $F(f)=0$ (the zero map)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The categories are either equivalent or not.  This doesn’t mean all functors between them are equivalences.  If two sets have the same cardinality, does that mean all functions between them are bijections?

Comment: It seems like it is a property of the categories because of the name *equivalent category*, though it would seem to make more sense to say, an equivalence relation implies that the categories have the same amount of isomorphism classes.

Comment: It IS a property of the categories.

Comment: Though isn't it equivalent to saying "Both categories have the same amount of isomorphism classes"

Comment: No. If you only care about *amounts*, that's set theory. Category equivalence also preserves the composition of morphisms. For a specific counterexample, take 2 categories of $2$ elements: the discrete one and one with an arrow. These are not equivalent, but both have $2$ nonisomorphic objects.